# Glassfish 3.1.1 cluster session replication

Tags: glassfish-3, failovercluster, session-replication

I've got problems with session replication on Glassfish 3.1.1 Open Source edition.
There are two physical servers included in on cluster. On the first one there is DAS and instance 1. On the second physical server there is instance 2. Both servers run Windows 7 x64. I am following this tutorial:

http://javadude.wordpress.com/2011/05/12/glassfish-3-1-%E2%80%93-clustering-tutorial-part2-sessions/

As far as I understand when session replication works there should the same session when I visit the web app one both physical instances. Thus, when I log in into instance 1, I should be automatically logged in on instance 2 as well. Is this right?

Does anybody know how to solve this problem?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you have any update on this issue? I have the same problem.